# Como alterar um evento de botão?

Tags: vb.net

Preciso alterar um evento .Click de um botão clicando em outro, mas não sei como fazer isso. Fazendo método comum de **Button1.Click =** , o programa me dá como erro.

Estou fazendo em VB.NET. Como posso alterar as configurações do evento dessa forma?

Comment: O que você já fez? qual erro esta sendo gerado ?

Answer (score 3):

Para remover o evento `Button1_Click`

```
RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
```

Para adicionar o evento `NovoEvento_Click`

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf NovoEvento_Click
```

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que você tenha um método:

```
Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 

End Sub
```

Pode associar ao evento `Click` da seguinte maneira:

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
```

Comment: Bá, não vi que você tinha respondido :P +1